# Running a jar file on unix (FileNotFoundException) Error due to slash inconsistency

Tags: java, unix, jar

I don't have any experience working with Java (just basic knowledge), and I am trying to run a Jar file on Unix system.
so I figured out how to run the file using the following command:

```
java -Xmx80000m -jar ProCon.jar -conv=PD1x -pks=Consensus [...and some other arguments...]
```

Note that I am running the jar file from my account on a cluster. So my path would be something like this:

```
scratch/user/ProCon/
```

The app starts running, however, I guess it gets confused to link to its resources as it throughs some errors and warnings:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\resources\obofiles\unimod.obo (No
> such file or directory)

or

> /scratch/user/ProCon\resources\taxonomy_ID_names.txt

in the example above, it seems as if the jar file reads my path but adds another path (resources\taxonomy_ID_names.txt) with a wrong slash, causing the model to get confused with the path and slashes.
is there any way to fix such issues?

The program I am using is P[ROTEOMICS CONVERSION TOOL (PROCON)](http://www5.rz.ruhr-uni-bochum.de:8666/mpc/software/ProCon/index.html.en). It can be downloaded from [THIS LINK: PROCON](http://www5.rz.ruhr-uni-bochum.de:8666/mpc/mam/content/Software/ProCon/procon_dist-0.9.804.zip)

Comment: Yes, it would appear the program your are running is not portable.  There are ways to fix programs that are not portable, but we can't advise you on *how* to do it unless you show us the relevant source code.

Comment: @StephenC The program I am using is PROTEOMICS CONVERSION TOOL (PROCON). I added the link to the question

Comment: Well it doesn't look like there is not any source code in that ZIP file.  So this is not a programming problem.  It is a support problem.  Contact the software suppliers for advice on what to do.